# SAP Odata service metadata do not output fully in browser

Tags: odata, sap-gateway

My MPC Provider is not fully providing metadata to the browser when called.

I am calling the service like follows:

```
http://SERVER/sap/opu/odata/sap/SERVICE/?$metadata
```

It's returning:

```xml
<app:service xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" xml:lang="en" xml:base="http://SERVER:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/SERVICE/">
  <app:workspace>
    <atom:title type="text">Data</atom:title>
    <app:collection sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:pageable="false" sap:content-version="1" href="hu_headerSet">
      <atom:title type="text">hu_headerSet</atom:title>
      <sap:member-title>hu_header</sap:member-title>
    </app:collection>
    <app:collection sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:pageable="false" sap:content-version="1" href="hu_itemSet">
      <atom:title type="text">hu_itemSet</atom:title>
      <sap:member-title>hu_item</sap:member-title>
    </app:collection>
  </app:workspace>
  <atom:link rel="self" href="http://SERVER:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/SERVICE/"/>
  <atom:link rel="latest-version" href="http://SERVER:8000/sap/opu/odata/sap/SERVICE/"/>
</app:service>
```

I'm expecting it to return the details of the two entity sets, including the properties of the entities and the associations, which is what it **should** do.

I've debugged the MPC which is getting all the attributes, associations, and entities, but these are not being output when called. I'm trying to generate an EDMX to create a new App, I've done this manually before, but both of these entitysets have 40/50 fields.

I've checked SU53 and there's no failed Authorzations, I've cleared the cache every time that  I've done a debug to make sure it's not that, and I've set the get_entity calls in the MPC to protected as a test.

Does anyone have any ideas?
For those who are more successful, here is a resource with some suggestions that I've already tried: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/15/entityset-of-an-odata-not-appearing-in-metadata/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
http://SERVER/sap/opu/odata/sap/SERVICE/$metadata
```

without the '?'

The responses are different.